# Reverse Order of Elements of Image

Tags: analysis

Say $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$. Let $f:X\to Y$ with $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$. Is there an operator or mathematical construction which transforms $f$ to $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1$, i.e. reverse the order of the elements of the image?

Comment: I think in this case it would be referred to as a "transposition" operation in abstract algebra. In general transpositions are their own inverses, and in this case you can see that applying this operation twice yields the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Define the operator $T$ as $T(f) = \sigma\circ f$ where $\sigma$ is an appropriate permutation on the codomain $Y$.